# Compute correlation coefficient python or grphlab

Tags: python, correlation

Let's say we have two 'SFrames' in GraphLab `SFrame1` and `SFrame2` which contain array of numeric values. I would like to compute the correlation coefficient between two vectors. Here is what I do:

```
import numpy as np
a = data_All_Features_rating1000_top5_nr['n_r'].to_numpy
b = data_All_Features_rating1000_top5_nr['n_r'].to_numpy

np.corrcoef(a,b)
```

and I receive this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'instancemethod' and 'int'
```

`a` and `b` contain interger values:

```
print a
print b
<bound method SArray.to_numpy of dtype: int
Rows: 5
[77887, 76271, 67092, 56837, 54695]>
<bound method SArray.to_numpy of dtype: int
Rows: 5
[77887, 76271, 67092, 56837, 54695]>
```

How can I simply calculate the linear correlation coefficient between the two above vectors? Thanks

Comment: I can't test this, but I'd guess you are missing the parenthesis after .to_numpy, i.e. data_All_Features_rating1000_top5_nr['n_r'].to_numpy() You are assigning the method to the variables, not calling the method.

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem was solved!